# How to send and receive an Array List from fragment to service

Tags: android, arraylist

I'm trying to send an Array List using broadcast and service intent here is code for sending Intent:

```
intent.putExtra(AUDIO_LIST, audioList)
```

and this is how I'm receiving

```
intent.getSerializableExtra(AUDIO_LIST) as ArrayList<AudioModel>
```

but at the end I get a runtime exception of this type

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value AudioModel(uri=content://media/external/audio/media, songTitle=Over the Horizon, songArtist=Samsung, songPath=/storage/emulated/0/Samsung/Music/Over_the_Horizon.mp3)
```

what's possible error here...

Comment: Does your class implement the `Serializable` interface

Comment: You can to have your class AudioModel implement Parcelable and use intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra()